# how to get out single json-value of post - querystring in javascript

Tags: json, parsing, post, aws-lambda

trying to solve this problem:

receiving a json-post-value from stripe-checkout-button/form into a lambda-function.

added additional input-tag into the form.

now json looks like this:

```
'''{"amountName":"2","stripeToken":"...","stripeTokenType":"card","stripeEmail":"..."}'''
```

i am using the json-data in the lambda-function.

code looks like this:

```
'''const qs = require('querystring'); api.post('/create-payment', (request) => {let body = qs.parse(request.body); return body.stripeToken;}); module.exports = api;'''
```

this works perfectly!

BUT - it should be exactly the same way to adress the added input-value of the form:

```
'''const qs = require('querystring'); api.post('/create-payment', (request) => {let body = qs.parse(request.body); return body.amountName;}); module.exports = api;'''
```

and this DOESNT work - results in "internal server error"!

if someone understands whats going wrong and could give me any advice - please feel free to do so!

i dont know either, if this error-msg comes from lambda or from somewhere else. i tried to console all sorts of other parse-codings, etc. but console doesnt work - only in html, not in lambda - which doesnt make it easier.

Comment: sorry, forgot to post the first code-lines:

use strict';

const ApiBuilder = require("claudia-api-builder");
const api = new ApiBuilder();

Comment: ok, fund a workaround, so problem solved, but i still dont understand why i received the error

var c = 0;
  Object.entries(body).forEach((entry) => {
    const [key, value] = entry;
    if (key == "amountName") {
        c = parseInt(value);
    }
  });

that gives me the value i searched finally!

Comment: everything fine now, also found out that the error definitely came from lambda. probably some problem with the format of the return of the function. still dont understand it completely as i tried with hundreds of stringifys and whatever - and still not understanding why i, once in lambda, cannot get access to the console.logs. but however - PROBLEM SOLVED - probably as someone of you thought in the right direction and transferred this to me without posting anything - so THANKS!